# I want to change the custom font of option menu in android( like: Centuary Gothic,Raleway Regular )

Tags: android, android-studio

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8qmI.png)

how i will set custom font my my android app option menu right size top of the screen. It should be custom font like Raleway Regular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class

```
public class Railway_Bold extends TextView {
public Railway_Bold(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf"));
}}
```

use this class to yout textview...

```
 <your_package_name.fonts.Railway_SemiBold
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Trending Articles"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
```